# Optimizing query with a partial index always results in a bitmap heap scan

Tags: postgresql

Query:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM my_table
WHERE
    create_date > '2014-01-01' AND create_date <= '2015-01-01' AND
    lower(first_name) = 'joe' AND first_name <> '' AND first_name is not null
```

Index I created:

```
CREATE INDEX bix_firstname
    ON my_table(create_date, lower(first_name))
    INCLUDE (id)
    WHERE first_name <> '' AND first_name is not null
```

The EXPLAIN I get (which I unfortunately cannot give the full result) looks something like this:

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table(cost=1310.36..165390.74 rows=54942 width=8)
        Recheck Cond: ((lower((first_name)::text) = 'joe'::text) AND ((first_name)::text <> ''::text))
        Filter: ((create_date > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (create_date <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

Now, the goal (if you can tell from my index), was to create an index that just includes the id so that I dont need to waste time retrieving all the row data from each page in the index. Problem is, it still treats the query like a heap scan.

Is this a circumstance of the partial index (since the condition requires the first name to exist) or am I missing something with my index?

**Edit**

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table(cost=1296.65..165789.10 rows=107 width=8) (actual time=26342.221..150079.264 rows=4 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((lower((first_name)::text) = 'joe'::text) AND ((first_name)::text <> ''::text))
        Filter: ((create_date > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (create_date <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 39285
        Heap Blocks: exact=15004
```

Comment: what if you omit `AND first_name <> '' AND first_name is not null`?  That seems redundant with `lower(first_name) = 'joe'`.  And can you share `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output (not just `EXPLAIN`) so we can know if the scan selection is based off inaccurate statistics?

Comment: Sure one sec - if I omit first_name <> '', it turns the query into a sequential scan.

Comment: You should reverse the column order in your index.  The column used for equality check should go before the one used for inequality.  Also, your chunks of EXPLAIN  ANALYZE have omitted the most important part, the Bitmap Index Scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index has the wrong order. It should be

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table (lower(first_name), create_date)
   INCLUDE (id)
WHERE first_name <> '' AND first_name IS NOT NULL;
```

The second column can only be used in an index scan if the comparison operator for the first column is `=`. This index will avoid the "rows removed by filter" if `work_mem` is set high enough to avoid lossy bitmap entries.